# Problema ao analisar expressões regulares de um jTextArea

Tags: java, regex

Estou tentado analisar um texto digitado em um jTextArea, na forma de um algoritmo em portugol. Inicialmente devo reconhecer o método principal, que se caracteriza por "inicio" e "fim".
Da forma que estou fazendo (código abaixo), minha lógica só funciona se tudo estiver na mesma linha, não importando o que há entre as duas palavras por exemplo:

inicio .... asdf fim

Eu preciso que ao digitar no jTextArea, a lógica funcione mesmo se a linha for quebrada por um Enter, por exemplo:

inicio
....
asdf
fim

O que posso fazer para funcionar?

```
      String a = jTextArea1.getText();

    //----- METODO PRINCIPAL ----
    boolean valInicio = a.matches("^inicio.*");
    boolean valFim = a.matches(".*fim$");
    if (valInicio) {
        jTextArea2.setText(jTextArea2.getText() + "\nEcontrou o inicio do programa!");
        if (valFim) {
            jTextArea2.setText(jTextArea2.getText() + "\nEcontrou o fim do programa!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Um jeito seria você dar um replace em todas as quebras de linhas antes de dar matche: `a.replace("\n", ":quebra:")`. Depois de checar você poderia voltar com o texto ao normal: `a.replace(":quebra:", "\n")`

Comment: Posteriormente eu vou precisar que meu código analise mais coisas dentro desse "código" digitado no jTextArea, como operadores relacionais, aritméticos, entre outros itens, independente de quantas linhas o código tiver. Utilizando essa forma será que funcionará para os próximos itens do meu trabalho?

Comment: Acredito que sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As flags [Pattern.DOTALL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) e [Pattern.MULTILINE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) podem te ajudar.

```
String patternString = "[\\s\\S]*^inicio.*[\\s\\S]*fim$[\\s\\S]*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.MULTILINE);
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(a).find());
```

Desta forma, qualquer texto que começar com `inicio`, terminar com `fim` e atender a algum dos critérios abaixo será encontrado pela regex:

- Possui quebra(s) de linha e/ou espaço(s) antes de "inicio"
- Possui quebra(s) de linha e/ou espaço(s) entre "inicio" e "fim"
- Possui quebra(s) de linha e/ou espaço(s) depois de "fim"

Comment: Deu certinho, muito obrigado Marcelo!